# SQL JOIN, GROUP BY on Four tables to get Record By Month

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, left-join

I have the following DB design. Tables are:

```
auth_user
----------
first_name
last_name

staffuser
----------
phone_number
user_id

billing_customerservicebill
-----------------------------
bill_id
service_provider_id
discounted_price

billing_billmanagement
------------------------
creation_date
```

My query return Sum of discounted_price each user by month row wise. I need every month record show in column.
The following query gives me This record

```
select a.service_provider_id, first_name, Sum(a.discounted_price), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM c.creation_date)
    from billing_customerservicebill a
         left outer join users_staffuser b
         on a.service_provider_id = b.id
         left outer join billing_billmanagement c
         on a.bill_id = c.id
         left outer join auth_user d 
         on d.id = b.user_id
    where c.creation_date between '2017-11-01' AND '2017-12-31'
    group by service_provider_id, first_name, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM c.creation_date)
    order by 1

My data show in Table Currently 
    service_provider_id | first_name | Sum     |  Month
      5                 |   suneel     31500   |  11
      5                 |   Suneel   | 900     |  12

Expected data is 
    service_provider_id | first_name | Nov     |  December
      5                 |   suneel   |  31500  |  900
```

Comment: Replace `between '2017-11-01' AND '2017-12-31' with `between `'2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'` to get the data from January to December.
`
`

Comment: NO No this is not my point. i want every month column

Comment: @zeeshan will it always be for 2 months?  SQL works on fixed columns.  So, yes this is easily done, but you need to predetermine exactly which columns you're going to calculate.

Comment: @MatBailie by the way i just give example. if i have years of records. then how we can show by month.

Comment: You need to determine how many months you want to show. As I said, sql works with fixed columns, you can't have a single sql statement that changes the number of columns it has based on the data. That's why sql uses the normalised structure you're starting with: it allows as many months as you like without needing extra columns. So, like I already asked, how many columns are you going to have?

Comment: Another question is Why do you want to do this? As it changes the structure from a sql friendly one to an unfriendly one, it's an important question. If it's going to be used in further sql processing, don't do it. If it's for presentation in a report, consider doing the formatting in the reporting application...

Comment: @MatBailie i need January to December record show in columns.

Comment: ALWAYS Jan to Dec?  Never Feb 2017 to Jan 2018, etc, etc?

Comment: @MatBailie actually i make monthly sale comparison report thats why i need this type of thing. if you have better solution then tell me.

Comment: sometime my boss say i need november to december report and some time he way jan to dec. its depend on his order.

Comment: If you want different numbers of months each time, do not put each month in its own column. That's not how SQL works, so I suggest doing this kind of Formatting in the report rather than SQL.  This will enable you to make this SQL for flexible, easier to test, re-usable, etc.  It also keeps presentation layers and data layers separated, another good design / engineering practice.  Your last option is to search for `dynamic-sql` or `dynamic-pivot`; this involve code that writes a new sql statement each time you run it, which should *normally* be a last resort rather than a first response.

Comment: @MatBailie if we use this pattern of sql then how we can discounted price show. DESC order.

Answer (score 2):

The most flexible approach is to use conditional aggregation...

```
select
    a.service_provider_id,
    first_name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.creation_date >= '2017-11-01' AND c.creation_date < '2017-12-01' THEN a.discounted_price END)   AS nov,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.creation_date >= '2017-12-01' AND c.creation_date < '2018-01-01' THEN a.discounted_price END)   AS dec
from billing_customerservicebill a
     left outer join users_staffuser b
     on a.service_provider_id = b.id
     left outer join billing_billmanagement c
     on a.bill_id = c.id
     left outer join auth_user d 
     on d.id = b.user_id
where c.creation_date between '2017-11-01' AND '2017-12-31'
group by service_provider_id, first_name
order by 1
```

This shows that you need to know in advance which columns you're going to calculate.

Comment: Thanks. this is query i want. you are champ

Comment: Now 1 more thing if i have 1 year record then how we can do by month

Answer (score 0):

Please, try with below solution it's near to your answer:
Where month as column and group by users:

```
select  B.service_provider_id, B.first_name, 
(case when month=1 then discounted_price else 0 end) as JAN, 
(case when month=2 then discounted_price else 0 end) as FEB, 
(case when month=3 then discounted_price else 0 end) as MAR, 
(case when month=4 then discounted_price else 0 end) as APR, 
(case when month=5 then discounted_price else 0 end) as MAY, 
(case when month=6 then discounted_price else 0 end) as JUN, 
(case when month=7 then discounted_price else 0 end) as JULY, 
(case when month=8 then discounted_price else 0 end) as AUG, 
(case when month=9 then discounted_price else 0 end) as SEP, 
(case when month=10 then discounted_price else 0 end) as OCT, 
(case when month=11 then discounted_price else 0 end) as NOV, 
(case when month=12 then discounted_price else 0 end) as DEC 
from(
select a.service_provider_id, first_name, Sum(a.discounted_price) as discounted_price, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM c.creation_date) as month
    from billing_customerservicebill a
         left outer join users_staffuser b
         on a.service_provider_id = b.id
         left outer join billing_billmanagement c
         on a.bill_id = c.id
         left outer join auth_user d 
         on d.id = b.user_id
    where c.creation_date between '2017-11-01' AND '2017-12-31'
    group by service_provider_id, first_name, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM c.creation_date)    
) as B
group by B.service_provider_id, B.first_name
```